# Laravel - Target [App\Interfaces\Auth\AuthInterface] is not instantiable while building

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8 application, I am trying to bind Repository to an Interface

I have this code:

App\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider:

```
class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            'App\Interfaces\Auth\AuthInterface',
            'App\Repositories\Auth\AuthRepository'
        );
    }
}
```

config\app:

```
App\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class,
```

Then the interface looks like this:

```
namespace App\Interfaces\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

interface AuthInterface
{
    public function register(Request $request);
}
```

Repository Implementation:

```
namespace App\Repositories\Auth;

use App\Interfaces\Auth\AuthInterface;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Traits\ApiResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AuthRepository implements AuthInterface
{
    use ApiResponse;

    public function register(DriverRequest $request)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $newUser = User::create([
                'first_name' => $request->first_name,
                'last_name' => $request->last_name,
                'email' => preg_replace('/\s+/', '', strtolower($request->email)),
                'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
            ]);

            DB::commit();
            return $this->success('Signup Successfully Done, please check your email to activate account', $newUser);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            Log::error($e);
            return $this->error($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
use App\Interfaces\Auth\AuthInterface;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    protected $authInterface;

    public function __construct(AuthInterface $auth)
    {
        $this->authInterface = $auth;
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->authInterface->register($request);
    }
}
```

When I did php artisan route:list, I got this error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

  Target [App\Interfaces\Auth\AuthInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Auth\AuthController].

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1049
1045▕         } else {
1046▕             $message = "Target [$concrete] is not instantiable.";
1047▕         }
1048▕
➜ 1049▕         throw new BindingResolutionException($message);
1050▕     }
1051▕
1052▕     /**
1053▕      * Throw an exception for an unresolvable primitive.

 1   C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:842
  Illuminate\Container\Container::notInstantiable("App\Interfaces\Auth\AuthInterface")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:714
  Illuminate\Container\Container::build("App\Interfaces\Auth\AuthInterface")
```

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe show the repository implementation?

Comment: @BrianThompson - I have added repository implementation in my code update

Comment: I'm guessing it's not detecting your service provider for some reason. Its not picking up that the interface should actually be dependency inverted to the implementation, so it's trying to it instantiate the interface. I would try adding logs to your service provider to make sure it's actually executing, and double check all of the namespaces for inconstancies.

Answer (score 0):

It might be from your namespace, I had the same issue...it came from my namespace